# On SO Careers, how come the presentation of dates on certifications is different?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

We can use [my SO Careers profile](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/thomasjowens) as an example.

One certification is listed as "December 2010 - Current". That's correct - I took the test in December 2010, passed it, and this particular certification never expires.

Another certification is simply listed as "2014". Technically, that's correct. However, it's not complete or consistent. This certification does not expire. I would like to list is as "April 2014" or "April 2014 - Current".

I looked at editing my profile, and it looks like you can't choose a month (anymore?). For completeness, it should be optional to specify a month. Some certifications should also have an optional expiration date.

In short:

- Certifications should have an optional month for both the start and end fields.
- Certifications should have three options for an end date. Certifications with an end date or expiration should have an optional end month/year. Certifications that don't expire should have a way to indicate this, with "current" being indicated in the text.

Comment: Looks like it was changed at some point, and in the previous design you could choose a  month, plus when not giving the "to" year (which is still optional) it made it default to "Current". Not sure it's a bug, but surely strange and better be changed or made consistent with past way of editing.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I think it's a bug that useful functionality was removed. Maybe it was intentional, but regardless of what happened, there was functionality that I want and now it's apparently gone. Maybe this should be a feature-request to bring it back?

Comment: Well, the team sometimes move the cheese around in Stack Exchange, e.g. in the recent profile page redesign lots of things have been moved/removed. But nothing wrong in asking to bring it back. :)

Comment: Looking into this...

Comment: @Max Thanks. Looking forward to an update.

Answer (score 3):

As correctly pointed out in the comments, in an earlier version of Careers it was possible to specify start and end *month* of a certification. There was also a checkbox to indicate that the certification is "current" (similar to other sections, e.g. "current job", "current education").

The month and "current" fields have subsequently been removed (feature suggestion above to bring them back has been noted for future consideration, we'll look at this as part of a larger overhaul of candidate profiles). We currently only allow entering the *year* the certification has been earned and, optionally, the year in which it expires. There is no such thing anymore as marking a certification as "current".

Due to a glitch, months and "- current" would still show up on certifications which have been entered before we made that change. This has now been fixed:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for making it consistent. I do hope that you add months, expiration, and currency back in. But for the time being, I'm happy with the consistency.